# Insert different values everytime when using insert into

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table which has 3 columns and 6 records, I want to insert the values in another table which has an additional column of sysid, when I use insert into clause it inserts the records but the sysid value is same , I want different values everytime a record insert but I want to insert in bulk as well

Answer (score 0):

Use a sequence:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE table_name__sysid__seq;
```

Then:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (sysid, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6)
VALUES (table_name__sysid__seq.NEXTVAL, 'value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5', 'value6');
```

or, for multiple rows:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (sysid, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6)
SELECT table_name__sysid__seq.NEXTVAL, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6
FROM   first_table;
```

Or else, if you are using Oracle 12 or later, define `sysid` as an `IDENTITY` column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  sysid NUMBER
        GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
        PRIMARY KEY,
  col1  VARCHAR2(20),
  col2  VARCHAR2(20),
  col3  VARCHAR2(20),
  col4  VARCHAR2(20),
  col5  VARCHAR2(20),
  col6  VARCHAR2(20)
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=4b835e00a65730d9c166e18419119a54)*